# java.lang.NullPointerException:at android.widget.PopupWindow.setContentView when trying to inflate Layout

Tags: android, android-inflate

I am trying to show a pop up window after an Image button is clicked. I created an additional layout for the pop up window and used the LayoutInflater to create a view from the layout. I am setting the popup window with this view using "setContentView"

```
 PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow();   
 LayoutInflater popupLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupWindowView = null;

        try{
            popupWindowView = popupLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popuplayout, null);
        }
        catch(InflateException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        if(popupWindowView!=null)
            popupWindow.setContentView(popupWindowView);
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(parentView, android.view.Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 10, 10);
    }
```

I get the following NullPointerException as the inflate function is returning a null.

```
05-29 00:20:08.582: W/dalvikvm(304): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x4001d800)
05-29 00:20:08.592: E/AndroidRuntime(304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 00:20:08.592: E/AndroidRuntime(304): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 00:20:08.592: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at     android.widget.PopupWindow.setContentView(PopupWindow.java:377)
05-29 00:20:08.592: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.widget.PopupWindow.<init>(PopupWindow.java:279)
05-29 00:20:08.592: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.widget.PopupWindow.<init>(PopupWindow.java:259)
05-29 00:20:08.592: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.widget.PopupWindow.<init>(PopupWindow.java:216)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for the problem. The error was with the line of code

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow();
```

This was implicitly calling the setContentView method. The code below works fine where I use another version of the PopupWindow constructor with View,height and width parameters.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

        LayoutInflater popupLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupWindowView = null;
        PopupWindow popupWindow = null;
        try{
            popupWindowView = popupLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popuplayout, null);
        }
        catch(InflateException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


        if(popupWindowView!=null)
        {
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupWindowView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }
        if(popupWindow!=null)
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(parentView, android.view.Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 100, 100);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For others who might have this error in future, i found on [sourceCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/widget/PopupWindow.java) that there is a constructor with PopupWindow(View contentView) and it is called.

So i found a workaround: instead of calling directly constructor i create a static method which returns an instance of this view. And it creates contentView first, pass to constructor so it can call directly super(contentView) constructor. And that's it.

```
public class MenuPopup extends PopupWindow {

    public static MenuPopup getInstance(Activity act) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null); 
        IvrMenuNew popup = new IvrMenuNew(act, contentView); 
        return popup;
    } 

    public MenuPopup (Activity act, View contentView) { 
        super(contentView); 
        // TODO: whatever else you need to do...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents to the solution.

If you have overridden constructor MyPopupWindow(Context context) and still get NullPointerException - check if you call super(context) at the first line, because you probably don't).